# Failure to understand javascript recursive program

Tags: javascript

I have written the following program in javascript:

```
function recursiveSum(a) {
  sum = 0;
  for (i=0;i<a.length; ++i) {
      if (typeof a[i] === "number") {
          sum += a[i];
      } else if (a[i] instanceof Array) {
          sum += recursiveSum(a[i]);
      }
  }
  return sum;
}
function arraySum(a) {

    // i will be an array, containing integers, strings and/or arrays like itself.
    // Sum all the integers you find, anywhere in the nest of arrays.

    return recursiveSum(a);
}
```

And I can't figure out why the result of `arraySum([[1,2,3],4,5])` [is 6](http://ideone.com/2K6JDK). Why the elements after the first array are not processed?

Comment: Where is your `sum` var defined? It may not be local to the function.

Comment: as soon as you can, type "use strict;"
at the beginning of all your js files. It doesn't allow your buggy style global variables without `var`.

Comment: I am a beginner in javascript and was writing code somewhat in association to other languages. I forgot to put `var` in front of the variables and so my variables are global as the answers suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a problem with Global Variables. You need to use `var`, it is not optional.

Both `sum` and `i` need to be declared with `var`.

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i=0;i<a.length; ++i) {
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `sum` and `i` variables are globals, because you haven't declared them as local to the function. You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). It's primarily the `i` variable that's causing the trouble with your specific input: Since your first entry in `a` is an array, `i` gets incremented by the recursive call, and the last two entries in the array are never processed by the outer call. (But if you'd used `[1, 2, [3, 4, 5]]`, the fact the calls share both `i` **and** `sum` would be causing trouble.)

Put `var` in front of each of them. Also look into using the new strict mode, which would have made that a useful error.